# Convert normal integer to 8 bit integer in PHP

Tags: php, signed-integer

I have an Integer 138 that i want to covert into an 8 bit signed Integer that will become -118.
I have tried unpack, intval and several othe php function but they didn't worked. 
How should i do this, stuck in this for few days now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be other ways, but a quick look at using `pack` and `unpack` - pack with `C` stores it as an unsigned and the unpack with `c` gets the signed value back...

```
echo unpack( 'c', pack('C', 138))[1];
```

gives

```
-118
```